# Error in jbpm sample project using persistence and postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jboss, jbpm, kie

I am trying to run a sample jbpm project in eclipse and I am using persistence.Whereas it gives an error on this line

RuntimeManager runtimeManager = RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newSingletonRuntimeManager(environment)

***Error :*** (I have also attached the error screenshot )
Any sort o[image]f information would be really helpful.

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, null, 2017-05-21 19:45:26.28, 0).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.BaseProxyHandlerClass.invoke(BaseProxyHandlerClass.java:64)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 36 more