# In jbpm6.5.0Final with posgres database ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jbpm, wildfly-10

I'm using jbpm6.5.0Final with Postgres database connection. When I try to start by jbpm-workbench container the following errors are showing:

> `KieSolverAssemblerService  09:06:34,547 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (MSC service thread 1-4) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502 09:06:34,547 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (MSC service thread 1-4) ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, null, 2017-10-09 09:06:34.48, 0).` 
> 09:06:34,550 WARN  [org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService] (MSC service thread 1-4) Could not commit session: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
> at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1152)
> at org.drools.persistence.jpa.JpaPersistenceContext.persist(JpaPersistenceContext.java:56)
> at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.(SingleSessionCommandService.java:110)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:171)
> at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:70)
> at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:39)
> at org.kie.internal.persistence.jpa.JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(JPAKnowledgeService.java:121)
> at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.factory.JPASessionFactory.newKieSession(JPASessionFactory.java:42)
> at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.SingletonRuntimeManager.init(SingletonRuntimeManager.java:97)
> at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.newSingletonRuntimeManager(RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.java:64)
> at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.manager.RuntimeManagerFactoryCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.newSingletonRuntimeManager(Unknown Source)
> at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.AbstractDeploymentService.commonDeploy(AbstractDeploymentService.java:134)
> at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService.deploy(KModuleDeploymentService.java:196)
> at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
> at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.initDeployments(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.java:128)
> at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy.initDeployments(Unknown Source)
> at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl.bootstrapDeployments(AdministrationServiceImpl.java:194)
> at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy.bootstrapDeployments(Unknown Source)
> at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:180)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98)
> at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
> at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:171)
> at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
> at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
> at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:162)
> at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
> at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:450)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
> at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
> at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
> at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
> at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
> at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2792)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3363)
> at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:597)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:232)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:213)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:256)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
> ... 64 more
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
> Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, null, 2017-10-09 09:06:34.48, 0).
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:622)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:472)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:429)
> at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
> ... 85 more

and also

> 09:06:34,597 INFO  [org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.store.DeploymentSynchronizer] (MSC service thread 1-4) Deployment unit org.guvnor:guvnor-asset-mgmt-project:6.5.0.Final removed successfully
> `09:06:34,853 ERROR [org.kie.remote.services.rest.jaxb.DynamicJaxbContextManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) JAXB context instance could not be found when undeploying deployment 'org.guvnor:guvnor-asset-mgmt-project:6.5.0.Final'!`
> 09:06:34,854 WARN  [org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unexpected error while deploying unit org.guvnor:guvnor-asset-mgmt-project:6.5.0.Final: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.AbstractDeploymentService.commonDeploy(AbstractDeploymentService.java:161)
> at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService.deploy(KModuleDeploymentService.java:196)
> at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
> at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.initDeployments(DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl.java:128)
> at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.DeploymentManagerEntryPointImpl$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy.initDeployments(Unknown Source)
> at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl.bootstrapDeployments(AdministrationServiceImpl.java:194)
> at org.jbpm.console.ng.bd.backend.server.AdministrationServiceImpl$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy.bootstrapDeployments(Unknown Source)
> at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup.assertPlayground(AppSetup.java:180)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98)
> at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
> at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:171)
> at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
> at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
> at org.kie.workbench.backend.AppSetup$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
> at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:162)
> at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
> at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:309)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:124)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:287)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:265)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
> at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:450)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
> at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
> at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
> at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:185)
> at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:70)
> at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:39)
> at org.kie.internal.persistence.jpa.JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(JPAKnowledgeService.java:121)
> at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.factory.JPASessionFactory.newKieSession(JPASessionFactory.java:42)
> at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.SingletonRuntimeManager.init(SingletonRuntimeManager.java:97)
> at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.newSingletonRuntimeManager(RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.java:64)
> at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.manager.RuntimeManagerFactoryCDIImpl$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.newSingletonRuntimeManager(Unknown Source)
> at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.AbstractDeploymentService.commonDeploy(AbstractDeploymentService.java:134)
> ... 49 more
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:171)
> ... 57 more
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
> at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1152)
> at org.drools.persistence.jpa.JpaPersistenceContext.persist(JpaPersistenceContext.java:56)
> at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.(SingleSessionCommandService.java:110)
> ... 62 more
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
> at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
> at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2792)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3363)
> at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:597)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:232)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:213)
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:256)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
> ... 64 more
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
> Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, null, 2017-10-09 09:06:34.48, 0).
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:622)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:472)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:429)
> at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
> ... 85 more

Comment: duplicate questions to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104328/error-in-jbpm-sample-project-using-persistence-and-postgres

Comment: ya i saw and post my comment there too but some one deleted my comment, and no answer there. You  know the answer for this? @hnandarusdy

Comment: I'm getting this error when i start the jbpm-workbench docker.

Comment: unfortunately, I am using mysql instead of postgres. This has not ever occured to me. However, from my point of view, you may need to alter some tables in postgres and apply the value with auto_increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all i got a solution for this. According to documentation from this site: `http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/jbpm6/configuring-jbpm-6-to-use-a-non-default-database` need to change the persistence.xml from jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml. This is available in deployment folder i moved this out and changed

> `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />`

to

> `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />`

and move jbpm-console.war to deployment folder through Dockerfile. Then without any change its starts working.